# Merging 2 tables with different field name

Tags: mysql

Select * From 'BatchA'

```
  Table 'BatchA'

  +--------+--------+--------+
  |Fruits  | color  |  class | 
  +--------+--------+--------+
  |        |        |        | 
  |Apple   |  Red   |    x   | 
  |Apple   | Yellow |    x   | 
  |Guava   | Green  |    o   | 
  +--------+--------+--------+
```

Select * From 'BatchB'
 Table 'BatchB'

```
  +--------+--------+--------+
  |FruitsB |  size  |  type  | 
  +--------+--------+--------+
  |        |        |        | 
  |  Apple |  Large |    A   | 
  |  Guava | Medium |    B   | 
  |  Guava |  Small |    C   | 
  +--------+--------+--------+
```

Is it possible to query with join or union using these results?

Result

```
  +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
  |Fruits  |  color |  class |Animals |  size  |  type  | 
  +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
  |        |        |        |        |        |        |  
  |  Apple |  Red   |    x   |        |        |        | 
  |  Apple | Yellow |    x   |        |        |        |    
  |        |        |        |  Apple |  Large |    A   |  
  |  Guava | Green  |    o   |        |        |        |
  |        |        |        |  Guava | Medium |    B   | 
  |        |        |        |  Guava |  Small |    C   | 
  +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: If you have any relation between those tables. Otherwise, you have to join those tables using row numbers.

Comment: `SELECT fruits, color, class, null, null, null FROM BatchA UNION ALL SELECT null, null, null, FruitsB, size, type FROM BatchB`

Comment: Please see my uptated question thanks

Comment: I flagged this to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking". You haven't explained at all what is your desired outcome is; just slapped the "result" table there.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT BatchA.*,null Animals,null size,null type FROM BatchA
UNION ALL
SELECT null,null,null,BatchB.* from BatchB;
```

This will list all rows from both tables with NULLs to those fields that aren't populated.

This is under the assumption that there is no relation between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` does not exist in MYSQL, try to imitate this functionality that is available in other DBMS such as ORACLE using a workaround as follows :

Use the union of left join and right join in 2 queries between the two tables (knowing that the tables are related):

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```